# ActionScript Math.abs() Conditional Not Working

Tags: actionscript-3, math, conditional-statements, absolute

i have a number variable, vx, that is changing with an enter frame event.  in the enter frame function i have the following code:

```
if  (Math.abs(vx) <= 0.05);
    {
    trace(Math.abs(vx));
    }
```

immediately, it's starts outputting numbers that are well above 0.05:

```
12.544444075226783
12.418999634474515
12.29480963812977
12.171861541748472
12.050142926330986
11.929641497067676
11.810345082097
11.69224163127603
11.575319214963269
11.459566022813636
11.3449703625855
11.231520658959644
11.119205452370048
11.008013397846348
10.897933263867884
10.788953931229205
10.681064391916912
10.574253747997743
10.468511210517764
10.363826098412586
10.260187837428461
10.157585959054176
10.056010099463634
9.955449998468998
9.855895498484308
```

does this make sense to anyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an extra colon `';'` after your if.

`if  (Math.abs(vx) <= 0.05)`**;**<--

Without i think it will works better:

```
if  (Math.abs(vx) <= 0.05) {
 trace(Math.abs(vx));
}
```

Comment: omg i'm so retarded.  how embarrassing!  thanks for seeing that.